# Excluding dates based upon a date value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have the below table.

I want to exclude rows where the start_cycle date is `>`than the date where the 'source' column `=` END_DATE. So for this example, removing any rows where the start_cycle date is > than 2/11/2019

END_DATE could be different for each ID

```
ID           START_CYCLE    END_CYCLE   SOURCE
1               1/20/2019   2/1/2019    START
1               2/2/2019    2/2/2019    START_BRA
1               2/3/2019    2/5/2019    ASSGN
1               2/6/2019    2/10/2019   CUST_START
1               2/11/2019   2/12/2019   ASSGN
1              2/11/2019    12/31/2999  END_DATE
1               1/1/3000    2/12/2019   END_DATE_BRA
```

For this example, expected results would be: (Removing the last row)

```
ID           START_CYCLE    END_CYCLE   SOURCE
1               1/20/2019   2/1/2019    START
1               2/2/2019    2/2/2019    START_BRA
1               2/3/2019    2/5/2019    ASSGN
1               2/6/2019    2/10/2019   CUST_START
1               2/11/2019   2/12/2019   ASSGN
1               2/11/2019   12/31/2999  END_DATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without a join, assuming that there is only 1 row for each `id` with `source = 'END_DATE'`:

```
select * from tablename t
where start_cycle <= (select start_cycle from tablename where id = t.id and source = 'END_DATE')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a CTE. First you will query for the START_CYCLE for all ID with SOURCE = 'END_DATE'. Afterwards you will join this Result:

```
WITH id_end_date as 
(
SELECT id, start_cycle
FROM table1
WHERE source = 'END_DATE'
)
SELECT to.*
FROM table1 to
INNER JOIN id_end_date
ON to.id = id_end_date.id
WHERE to.start_cycle > id_end_date.start_cycle
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the query, Assuming there would be multiple ID's in the table.

```
select from <tableName> t1 inner join (select * from <tableName> where source='END_DATE') t2 
on t1.id=t2.id and t1.start_cycle > t2.start_cycle;
```